# Can I Remove GUI From Debian?

Tags: debian, gui, uninstall

I just did my first install of any Linux OS, and I accidentally selected "Desktop GUI" in the install, but I want to build everything myself. Is there any way by which I can remove the GUI environment without re-installing OS?

Comment: From what I've seen, there are always many GUI packages missed by the uninstall methods (one can see them with `dpkg --get-selections` as per @daniel-bank's comment). If using the method of removing base packages, then autoremoving the rest, it's easy to lose desired packages that were installed as dependencies. `apt-mark` can set them as explicitly installed, preventing automatic removal, but the end result is never as clean as a fresh install would have been.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Debian uses `tasksel` for installing software for a specific system. The command gives you some information:

```
> tasksel --list-tasks
i desktop       Graphical desktop environment
u web-server    Web server
u print-server  Print server
u dns-server    DNS server
u file-server   File server
u mail-server   Mail server
u database-server       SQL database
u ssh-server    SSH server
u laptop        Laptop
u manual        manual package selection
```

The command above lists all tasks known to `tasksel`. The line *desktop* should print an `i` in front. If that is the case you can have a look at all packages which this task usually installs:

```
> tasksel --task-packages desktop
twm
eject
openoffice.org
xserver-xorg-video-all
cups-client
…
```

On my system the command outputs 36 packages. You can uninstall them with the following command:

```
> apt-get purge $(tasksel --task-packages desktop)
```

This takes the list of packages (output of `tasksel`) and feeds it into the `purge` command of `apt-get`. Now `apt-get` tells you what it wants to uninstall from the system. If you confirm it everything will be purged from your system.

Comment: Hm, what do you make of this, with `tasksel --task-packages desktop` I only get `task-desktop`? But I have some of those packages (e.g., twm).

Comment: What is the output of `tasksel --list-tasks | grep "^i"`? Is the package `desktop-base` installed?

Comment: `tasksel --list-tasks | grep "^i"` doesn't give my anything: I have only `u` lines for `tasksel --list-tasks`, including `u desktop Debian desktop environment`. `aptitude show desktop-base` says that package (`desktop-base`) is installed, though. Are those related? I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: This answer partially worked for me, but I also had to: `dpkg --get-selections` (showed me that I had `xserver` packages installed), `apt-get purge xserver-*` (delete all the xserver packages).

Comment: @qbi I am on mint, and `tasksel --list-tasks` shows no option for desktop in my case i stands for LAMP server

Answer (score 10):

It means Debian changed the behaviour of this by now using a single "meta" package called task-desktop which pulls in the other packages via dependencies and recommends. So it's true what tasksel tells you, it just installs that single package, but if you look at the details of that, like so:

```
apt-cache show task-desktop
```

you will see the other (actual) packages this pulls in in the lines starting "Depends:" and "Recommends:". To remove them try "apt-get remove task-desktop" or list the package names individually.

Comment: You can just uninstall the _task-desktop_ package and the do a `apt-get autoremove` to purge the dependencies.

Comment: `apt autoremove --purge` to purge also the dependent packages

Answer (score 3):

```
apt purge task-desktop hyphen-en-us libglu1-mesa libreoffice-* libu2f-udev mythes-en-us x11-apps x11-session-utils xinit xorg xserver-* desktop-base task-german task-german-desktop totem gedit gedit-common gir1.2-* gnome-* gstreamer* sound-icons speech-dispatcher totem-common xserver-* xfonts-* xwayland gir1.2* gnome-*
```

then

```
apt autoremove --purge
```

to purge all dependent packages as well.

Comment: Correct, but I wouldn't call those dependent, but dependable.